# How to write an expression in the desired form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, factorization

I have the following code:

```
substitute1 = {x_ Conjugate[x_] -> Abs[x]^2};
substitute2 = {x_ + Conjugate[x_] -> 2 Re[x]};
S0 = {{Sv, 0}, {0, Sh}};
R[ϕ_] := {{Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]}, {-Sin[ϕ], Cos[ϕ]}};
S = Dot[R[ϕ], S0,  Refine[ConjugateTranspose[R[ϕ]], ϕ ∈ Reals]];
vvvvPre = Refine[Distribute[Conjugate[S[[1, 1]]]], ϕ ∈ Reals]

(*Conjugate[Sv] Cos[ϕ]^2 + Conjugate[Sh] Sin[ϕ]^2*)

vvvv = Expand[S[[1, 1]]*vvvvPre] /. substitute1

(*Abs[Sv]^2 Cos[ϕ]^4 + 
 Sv Conjugate[Sh] Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
 Sh Conjugate[Sv] Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 + 
 Abs[Sh]^2 Sin[ϕ]^4*)
```

I want to write `vvvv` finally as follows:
$$|S_v|^2\cos^4\phi+2\Re(S_h S_v^* )\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi+|S_h|^2\sin^4\phi$$
The solution is to `factorize` $\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi$ and then when $S_h S_v^*$ and $S_v S_h^*$ lie next to each other, we can use `substitute2`
but I don't know how to write the code for this part?

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of substitute2 define more general substitute3:

```
substitute3 = {a_.*Conjugate[x_] + x_.*Conjugate[a_] :> 2 Re[a*x]};
```

Then your can replace as follows:

```
Collect[vvvv, {_Cos, _Sin}] /. substitute3
```